# How to calculate ratios and create a pivoted output of joined tables in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables orders and advertisement. Both are joined but now need to be pivoted. How does a regular pivot function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just count the number of users in the test and subscription and take the ratio for each group:

```
SELECT e.experiment_id,
       SUM( e.experiment_assignment = 'test' AND s.user_id IS NOT NULL AND s.subscription_event = 'subscription_start') / SUM(e.experiment_assignment = 'test') as test_ratio,
       SUM( e.experiment_assignment = 'control' AND s.user_id IS NOT NULL AND s.subscription_event = 'subscription_start') / SUM(e.experiment_assignment = 'test') as control_ratio
FROM experiments e LEFT JOIN 
     subscriptions s 
     ON e.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY e.experiment_id;
```

This assumes that the users are not duplicated in either table for a specific experiment.

EDIT:

If there are duplicates use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT e.experiment_id,
       (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.experiment_assignment = 'test' AND s.subscription_event = 'subscription_start' THEN s.user_id END) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.experiment_assignment = 'test' THEN e.user_id END) 
       ) as test_ratio,
       (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.experiment_assignment = 'control' AND s.subscription_event = 'subscription_start' THEN s.user_id END) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.experiment_assignment = 'control' THEN e.user_id END) 
       ) as control_ratio
FROM experiments e LEFT JOIN 
     subscriptions s 
     ON e.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY e.experiment_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I run this, I get 100% conversion for all classes except for experiment_id=2 and control_ratio TRUE. The calculations for the other 3 classes do not look right as they are not going to be 100%. could you check one last time?

Comment: I think it is missing something to the effect that the numerator of the conversion is subscription_event='subscription_start'.... :(